Enable Edit as Draft for Articles for Salesforce Experience Users
I need help enabling the "Edit as Draft" functionality for community users in a Salesforce Experience Cloud site. I’ve already provided all necessary permissions (object, field, and data category access), but the option is still not available. Are there additional configurations required?

Edit as draft action visibility issue in knowledge layout
Edit As draft action is only visible if Enable Lightning Knowledge is checked from Knowledge Settings from Setup
Setup-> Knowledge Settings -> Enable Lightning Knowledge 
Now the Edit As Draft button would be visible in both classic and lightning experience Knowledge Layout

Hi Tushar Jadav,
I already enabled the Lightning Knowledge. Also the button is already parent in the page layout but still it is not visible to salesforce Experience cloud or Community users.
Thanks for your answer.
